# Char to int, only using capital letters?

Tags: java

The point of the program is to take in a string, and advance each letter by a certain number, but for it to loop back around after Z. So A+14 = O, but R+14=F and Z+14=N. How do I change this line to make it work like that?

```
private static char[] advanceArray(char[] array, int n) {
    int length = array.length;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(array[i]!=' '){
        char ch = array[i];
        //ch += (char) ch+n;
        array[i]=ch;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

This is the full program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConvertString {
public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println("Enter a string to advance:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine().trim();
    char[] array = stringToArray(str);
    System.out.println("Enter int to advance:");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    array = advanceArray(array,n);
    printNewArray(array);
}

private static void printNewArray(char[] array) {
    String str = "";
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        str += array[i];
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}

private static char[] advanceArray(char[] array, int n) {
    int length = array.length;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(array[i]!=' '){
        char ch = array[i];
        ch += (char) ch+n;
        array[i]=ch;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

private static char[] stringToArray(String str) {
    int length = str.length();
    char[] ch = new char[length];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        ch[i]=str.charAt(i);
    }
    return ch;
}
}
```

Comment: How did you arrive at R+14=F?

Comment: `6 = (18+14) % 26`.  Take it from there.

Comment: The idea is that I want it to take in R and convert it to F, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that because adding an int to ch will not loop around to A after Z, it goes to [ instead.

Comment: After you do: ch += (char) ch+n.

you could have another if statement saying if ch > 23 or whatever index z is, ch -= 23. This should loop back to the beginning which is A.

Comment: .. which should just be `ch += n;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
private static char[] advanceArray(char[] array, int n) {
int length = array.length;
for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
    if(array[i]!=' '){
    int ch = (int)array[i];

    if(ch>96 && ch<123)
    {
        ch = ch-97;
        ch = ((ch+n)%26)+97;
    }
    else if(ch>64 && ch<91)
    {
        ch = ch-65;
        ch = ((ch+n)%26)+65;
    }

    array[i]=(char)ch;
    }
}
return array;
}
```

explanation

- In your code you have this statement `ch += (char) ch+n;`. You do not need to add char to it existing value it will mess up and take the value of ch over 26. But if that is the requirement of program you need to take the ch=ch%26 after that statement.
- I made the ch int and changed it's value to 0. It is just so you can understand it easily. This can be done in one line itself.
- I added code for capital char's. I think that might be part of your requirement. If it is not you can just remove the else statement and it will leave capital letter unchanged.
- Also, based on your code it seemed like you want to leave the anything other than alphabet unchanged.This code does that.

output

```
Enter a string to advance:
Hello world!
Enter int to advance:
6
Nkrru cuxrj!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the resultant value exceeds `Z`'s ASCII value and if yes, add the remaining bits into `A`'s value for rounding, e.g.:

```
private static char[] advanceArray(char[] array, int n) {
    int length = array.length;
    int aChar = 65;
    int zChar = 90;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(array[i])){
            char ch = array[i];
            int increment = ch + n; 
            ch = (char) (increment > zChar ? aChar + (increment - zChar - 1) : increment);
            array[i]=ch;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using only capital letters, you can do this simply with the modulo operator, %:

```
ch = (char) (ch + n - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
```